# Very own element attributes (browser support)

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a small project, which changes site content on load.
I used `data-*`attributes, and after job has been done (script replaces what has to be replaced) they would get removed.

However, I realized my very own attributes worked also. So instead of

```
data-myAttribute="value"
```

I could simply used

```
myAttribute="value"
```

What is browser support on those attributes?

(My very own attributes worked on Chrome v57)

Comment: You should use data-. What happens if HTML6 adds a myAttribute that does something different? They will never add any starting with data-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much add any attribute you want to any HTML tag. However, this is *not* supported by the HTML standard. It does work in pretty much any browser, but it *might* not be supported in the future. In addition, HTML validators will reject your HTML as invalid if you use non-standard attributes.

The whole reason we have `data-*` attributes is because those are standardized and are guaranteed to be supported and accepted by validators, and also are guaranteed to not clash with any future attributes that might get added to HTML.

Do not use custom attributes without the `data-*` prefix, as that might make your HTML break without any warning as the HTML standard evolves.

As for the question itself: As this is non-standard, browser support is not documented.